# Documenting if statements in doxygen

Tags: python, documentation, doxygen

How do i document a if statment in doxygen, it documents all my classes, fucntions but the comment i write for if statments, it considers for the next nearest variable.

```
if abc != "":  # Here we check if abc is not equal to null and then check if it is equal to some known values
    if abc != "red":
        if abc != "blue":
            error()

if gfh != ""
    ghf = 0
```

it is assigning the comment to the "ghf = 0" , any idea how to assign the comment to if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doxygen is a tool to generate an API documentation. That is, documentation on functionality and usage having writers of client code as a target audience in mind. These naturally don't care about implementation details.

What you appear to do is adding documentation for maintainers of your code. That is a different thing, which is not addressed by Doxygen.

I don't know if there are tools that help you document your control flow, besides some general rules-of-thumb for code readability:

- avoid "spaghetti code"
- give variables/functions meaningful names
- write meaningful docstrings

For example, you could introduce a function that performs the checks and returns a boolean value accordingly. This improves readability purely by using standard language features.

```
# you don't even need a comment to find out what the intention is here
if is_invalid(abc):
    error()
```

Also have a look at [this post](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/style/), and maybe also [IPython Notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html) might be something worth checking out.

Comment: So which tool do you recommend for my usage?

Comment: @Ashok I'd say you mostly don't need a tool for this, as long as you focus on readability when writing code. Have a look at my update for some hints.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation! helped alot

Comment: Actually I can think of a case: When you're required to document you branching operations for external testers.